# replacing a range of values with one value

Tags: python, pandas

I have a list that I'm adding to a pandas data frame it contains a range of decimal values. 
I want to divide it into 3 ranges each range represents one value

```
sents=[]
for sent in sentis:
if sent > 0:
    if sent < 0.40:
        sents.append('negative')
    if (sent >= 0.40 and sent <= 0.60):
        sents.append('neutral')
    if sent > 0.60
        sents.append('positive')
```

my question is if there is a more efficient way in pandas to do this as i'm trying to implement this on a bigger list and

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `pd.cut` to produce the results that are of type `categorical` and have the appropriate labels.

In order to fix the inclusion of `.4` and `.6` for the `neutral` category, I add and subtract the smallest float epsilon

```
sentis = np.linspace(0, 1, 11)
eps = np.finfo(float).eps

pd.DataFrame(dict(
        Value=sentis,
        Sentiment=pd.cut(
            sentis, [-np.inf, .4 - eps, .6 + eps, np.inf],
            labels=['negative', 'neutral', 'positive']
        ),
    ))

   Sentiment  Value
0   negative    0.0
1   negative    0.1
2   negative    0.2
3   negative    0.3
4    neutral    0.4
5    neutral    0.5
6    neutral    0.6
7   positive    0.7
8   positive    0.8
9   positive    0.9
10  positive    1.0
```

Comment: Thanks a lot exactly what i'm looking for

Answer (score 0):

List comprehension:

```
['negative' if x < 0.4 else 'positive' if x > 0.6 else 'neutral' for x in sentis]
```